# Use Different version of package for two nuget package C# .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, reference, nuget, .net-4.8

I need to use to use two packages Package1 & Package2 both in same project (same .csproj file)

But both need different version of Bond.Core.CSharp how do i use both packages.
Dependency is like:

Package1
-> dependency -> dependency -> dependency -> Bond.Runtime.Csharp 9.0.3-> Bond.Core.CSharp 9.0.3

Package2 -> dependency -> Bond.Runtime.Csharp 9.0.3-> Bond.Core.CSharp 9.0.3

```
<PackageReference Include="Package1" Version=.. /> 
   expect "Bond.Core.CSharp" Version="9.0.1"

<PackageReference Include="Package2" Version=.. /> 
   expect "Bond.Core.CSharp" Version="9.0.3" />
```

TargetFrameWork = .Net Framework 4.7.2

Comment: I'd expect dependency resolution to handle this automatically and resolve to 9.0.3. If you could provide a [mcve] so we could reproduce the problem, it would make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first package requires 9.0.1 and the second 9.0.3, you can try requiring directly version 9.0.3 in you project. I would expect Package1 to be fine with the version you are already requiring.

In other words, add a `PackageReference` for the desired version of `Bond.Runtime.Csharp` in order to ease the resolution of conflicts.